# Using recursion in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, xcode, recursion, boolean

I tried to do recursion loop in C using Xcode.
The code is for 7boom game that i should try it as my homework.
I tried to use recursion but my Xcode is stack and shows an errors.

Here is my code:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
    int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
     {
       BOOL reverse( int num);
       @autoreleasepool {
            int i;
            int num1;
            int num2;
            NSLog(@"Hello, World!");
           for ( i = 1; i<=20; i++){
               num1 = i / 10;
               num2 = i;
               if(i == 7){
                  NSLog(@"boom, i=%d", i);
                 i++;
              }
             if(i % 7 ==0){
                 NSLog(@"boom i=%d", i);
                 i++;
             }
            if(!reverse(i)){
               NSLog(@"boom reverse");
               i++;
             }
        NSLog(@"%d", i);
      }  
    }
   return 0;
  }
BOOL reverse (int num)
{
   if(num == 7)
       return (true);
   else
       reverse(num % 10); 
    return (false);
}
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: It seems odd that you are using both recursion and a loop in the reverse function.

Comment: it is show: "hello world!", and then the console is stuck...

Answer (score 4):

This will never return for a number like 6 ( or most numbers )

```
BOOL reverse (int num)
{
    if(num == 7)
        return (true);
    else
        reverse(num % 10); 
    return (false);
}
```

6 does not equal 7, 6 mod 10 = 6 repeat until stack overflows.

The rest of your code seems a bit suspicious as well, you should always avoid manipulating the control variable of a for loop within the loop.

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to have it do?

Comment: i try to find if in the number "num" one of the digits equal to 7

Comment: well if (num == 7) does that, what's the recursion for?

Answer (score 0):

It's homework, so hints only...

You appear to understand what an `if` does, and an `else`.

What is the *function* or *algorithm* that `reverse` is meant to be performing?

Is it to return `true` if and only if the most significant (leftmost) digit of the integer is a `7`?

So you've got two cases: numbers less than 10, and those not. Write some code to distinguish those two cases.

Now what must you do in the first case? Add that to your code.

And what must you do in the second case (hint: recurse maybe?)? Add that to your code.

Done.

*(Well apart from the concerns other raised about `for` iteration, which defines two variables `num1` and `num2` you don't use and alters the control variable `i` - this loop probably doesn't do what you think it does!)*